# Can't install the Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2

Tags: xero-api

I cannot install the Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2 Nuget package from either VS2017 or VS2019. The error is:

> Could not install package 'Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2 3.16.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

While my web app is .NET Framework version 4.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xero NetStandard SDK targets .NET Standard 2.0 and is only compatible with .NET Framework > 4.6.1.
You can see all the compatible frameworks for .NET Standard 2.0 here:

[.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)